# Why didn't Ayn Rand go on strike?

Tags: objectivism, ayn-rand

One of the key messages of Ayn Rand's book *Atlas Shrugged* is that you should go on strike and not share your achievements with the world since they will be used against you anyway. People vilify achievements and value mediocrity? Let them see what that attitude gets them (destruction).

I'm no expert on Rand's life, but AFAIK, and from researching a bit online, she never went on strike herself. She wrote many books, sold millions of copies, gave interviews, wrote a newsletter, had students, agreed to have some of her books turned into movies, and so on. These achievements were then used against her in due course, as her philosophy predicts.

Is Rand a hypocrite for not following her own philosophy by sharing it with the world – or is there something I'm not seeing?

PS: Please don't use this question as an opportunity to lay into Rand (for example, I've already heard the claim that she was a hypocrite for accepting social welfare later in life – mentioning it now since somebody is bound to bring it up). I'm genuinely interested if there's something I'm not seeing as I'm guessing this is *my* mistake not hers.

Comment: IIRC, she says somewhere that the conditions justifying the Strike (note that *The Strike* was the working title of *Atlas Shrugged*) did not obtain in the real America of her time. She was not so aggressive as some of her followers tend to be; remember that Dagny Taggart would have hesitated to shoot a helpless rabbit even if she did shoot a man helping hold John Galt hostage.

Comment: Her success wasn't used against her. The *content of her philosophy* was used against her. If she had invented something that made the world better, people wouldn't hate her no matter how successful she was. You're hiding this distinction by using the ambiguous word "achievements".

Comment: 1. Her financial success was used against her by forcing her to share her money with others and to finance policies she might disagree with or that might harm her. 2. The content of her philosophy wouldn't be known to as many people and thus couldn't be used against her as much if she hadn't been successful. 3. It's not true that people would like her if she had invented something that made the world better (and I think she did) – as she explains in *Atlas Shrugged*, lots of ppl *dislike* when people make the world better.

Comment: "as she explains in Atlas Shrugged" - as she *claims* in Atlas Shrugged. You're still using loaded words.

Comment: Do you have a refutation of her claim?

Comment: FWIW I think she does more than just claim. She explains a great deal, too. I go into some detail here: https://blog.dennishackethal.com/posts/charity-vs-justice

Comment: "People should go on strike" wasn't the message of the book. The national strike by the most productive people was a speculative response to the problems of society that Rand was concerned with. It might be taken as a suggestion for how the productive people could respond to the problems of society, but even that is too strong because there is reason to think from the works of fiction that Rand thought such a strike would improve the situation in real life.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Assuming you mean 'NO reason' to think a strike would improve the situation in real life – Rand seems to have viewed *Atlas Shrugged* as a way of teaching people her philosophy, fiction or not. And Oism is a "philosophy for living on earth". Together, these points provide a bridge from her fiction to real life, I think. What I'm reading between the lines of your comment is that her work shouldn't be taken so seriously or literally – I can't imagine she'd agree. If "People should go on strike" wasn't the message of the book, what do you think "Atlas Shrugged" means?

Comment: You are conflating wildly different things. There is no reason to think she intended for her fictional story to inspire real-life emulators. That is not remotely the same as saying that she didn't intend to convey a message or that her work shouldn't be taken seriously. Tolkien intended for his work to be taken seriously and meant for it to have a message, but he didn't intend for people to go looking for orcs to kill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One of the key messages of Ayn Rand's book Atlas Shrugged is that you should go on strike and not share your achievements with the world since they will be used against you anyway. People vilify achievements and value mediocrity? Let them see what that attitude gets them (destruction).

In AS the government and its corporate cronies make laws to expropriate productive people. This is enabled by people having contempt and hatred for productive people. According to Rand, this isn't an innocent mistake: anyone with a brain can spot that government intervention in the economy makes everyone worse off so the only reason for doing it is malice. As a result the strikers decide that if people don't want productive people around then they should leave.

> I'm no expert on Rand's life, but AFAIK, and from researching a bit online, she never went on strike herself. She wrote many books, sold millions of copies, gave interviews, wrote a newsletter, had students, agreed to have some of her books turned into movies, and so on. These achievements were then used against her in due course, as her philosophy predicts.

Rand's philosophy doesn't predict abuse of productive people. It sez if such people are abused they are under no obligation to provide their services and they should consider withdrawing them.

The world of AS is worse than the real world in some respects. Governments and their cronies are corrupt, malicious and stupid as described in AS. For example, the Manhattan project had a medical wing that deliberately poisoned American citizens with radioactive material without their consent

https://bioethicsarchive.georgetown.edu/achre/final/intro_3.html

And governments have committed even worse crimes, such as deliberately stealing food from people to starve them to death (many communist regimes) or murdering people in camps (Nazis and the British government during the Boer war). However, there is a substantial minority of people who dislike this kind of thing and are willing to say so.  So the real world isn't quite as bad as the world of AS at least in some countries.

Comment: So in essence, it sounds like you're suggesting that things were never bad enough in the real world for Rand to go on strike herself – got it, thanks.

Comment: +1 For noting that while she was rightfully opposed to collectivist and governmental abuses, but that she unironically used "going on strike", a literal collectivist action and never did so (either literally or metaphorically) because her later experience of the world was derived from her upper-class lifestyle that benefited from her "radical capitalism". It's easy to be cavalier to altruism when you have a full belly and wealthy groupies. No one 
"strikes" when they benefit from chanting "yay me, boo altruism" and passing it off as rigorous ethics and epistemology.

Comment: A person refusing to work for people who despise him isn't a collectivist action. Rand's epistemology is mostly no worse than that of most philosophers and in some respects it is better https://direct.curi.us/1579-objectivist-and-popperian-epistemology

Comment: J D, your writing is confusing. "+1 For noting that while she [...] but that she [...] and never did so" wut? I think you mean '+1 for noting that she was rightfully opposed to collectivist and governmental abuses, but she...' and so on. Otherwise, it sounds like you're attributing things to alanf that I don't think he wrote or meant.

Answer (score 5):

In the general sense, a *strike* is a collective work-stoppage meant to give leverage against a powerful industry-owner, usually to protest and redress poor working conditions. Rand — in her inimitable way — has reframed things to cast nation-states as the powerful industry-owners and place 'men of mind' (wealthy industrialists, prominent artists, inventors, etc.) as the unfairly treated laborers suffering under poor working conditions. The question raised by much of the book is how a railroad baron or copper magnate can possibly thrive when weighed down by regulations, taxes, and other governmental oppression. This sets up the John Galt plot line where 'men of mind' cease to contribute their efforts to society, or actively sabotage their own industries (similar to the way labor unions might cease labor at a factory or monkey-wrench equipment to shut down production). The ideal is that a walk-out by economic creators should shut down the national economy and force the government into compliance, which is essentially what happens in the book.

Not much is said in the book about what happens to the *actual* laborers who work for these striking 'men of mind'. One assumes there was a significant die-off…

Even under this principle, however, Rand herself would not feel an obligation to go on strike. In the context of the novel, she would place herself in the role of John Galt: the philosophical voice promoting and organizing the collective activity. Philosophers of that type cannot remove themselves entirely from the greater nation; they need to continue spreading the philosophical ideal even as economic creators are withdrawing their efforts. There would be no hypocrisy here even if the premises of the novel were true and the kind of draconian proto-nationalist governmental structure she imagined were realistic, as opposed to a hyper-capitalist fever-dream.

There are plenty of other things we can critique Rand on, no need for over-reach.

Comment: "Rand herself would not feel an obligation to go on strike. In the context of the novel, she would place herself in the role of John Galt" Galt went on strike (or 'quit' or whatever we want to call it). He purposely kept his greatest invention (his motor) from the world. He only shared his philosophy with more than a select few once the collapse of society was imminent. PS When I asked people not to shit on Rand, that includes plausibly deniably.

Comment: @DennisHackethal: We could argue about your first point, but even if true I don't think it counters the point that modern Western countries haven't rises to the level where a 'men of mind' strike might be useful or needed. Not even in the EU, much less the US... And apologies, but being asked to take Rand seriously leaves a bad taste in my mouth. I wasn't aiming for deniability, just bleeding off steam instead of spitting fire.

Comment: This is similar to my line of thinking when I read the question.  Why would someone who wrote the John Galt monologue _not_ want to share her philosophy with others?  I think it's pretty clear from Atlas Shrugged that she approved of spending large amounts of time educating the public on her ideals, and did not see that as a bad thing.

Comment: @JMac Then why did Galt stay hidden and refuse to share his philosophy with the world until the collapse of society was imminent?

Comment: @JMac To be clear, I think you'll find the answer to your question in the answer to mine.

Answer (score 1):

> One of the key messages of Ayn Rand's book Atlas Shrugged is that you should go on strike and not share your achievements with the world since they will be used against you anyway. People vilify achievements and value mediocrity?

The best term I've come across to describe Rand's activities in relation to philosophy is [public philosopher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_philosophy). From WP:

> Some public philosophers are academic professionals, such as Cornel West, Jürgen Habermas, Martha Nussbaum, Richard Rorty,[6] James Tully, Jack Russell Weinstein , but others may work outside of the usual academic contexts of teaching and writing for peer-reviewed journals such as social activist Jane Addams[7] and novelist Ayn Rand.[8]

That obviously puts Rand in a pickle because on the one hand, she recognized the phenomenon of what I often call "the conspiracy of mediocrity" wherein people who often see beyond the contours of their immediate milieu are indeed confronted and sabotaged by those who are afraid, jealous, and petty towards those who are more individual with their intellect and accomplishment. But on the other hand, what good is having good thoughts and writing novels if no one reads them? Thus, on the face, their seems to be a contradiction.

That being said, [Objectivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objectivism), which is a better-thought-out position on contemporary libertarianism than the sort embraced by preppers and right-wing extremists is an intellectual rather than visceral credo that does have a currency with libertarian-leaning (mainly US) intellectuals in the same way that Austrian economics does. If one has the same sort of disposition to resist communal and communist thinking (which was obviously a more threatening political reality when she was alive then today for intellectuals), then one would need to know that others are also resistant to the overarching demands to identify with some collectivist political identity.

Thus, Rand, who was clearly no idiot, was walking a fine line between "going on strike" and sharing her achievements with the world because she was attempting to share her achievements, not with the "world", but rather like minded-intellectuals. In fact, what you need to understand is that **"going on strike" is a metaphor, and it makes sense in the context that she had little hope in society, certainly many people, and had a distrust of government. Thus, "going on strike" is not a call to asceticism as you seem to be suggesting, but rather a call to skepticism, specifically in relying on others. In this way, Rand was and will always be thoroughly entrenched in the [American Myth of Rugged Individualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rugged_individualism)**. (Myth here invoking the sense of over-arching narrative or element of worldview rather than critique of the values it represents.)

Comment: "But on the other hand, what good is having good thoughts and writing novels if no one reads them?" Presumably you wouldn't write the novels in the first place. Or you could write them solely for your own pleasure. Galt did build the motor, after all, but kept it hidden. *Atlas Shrugged* says that acting in a way that harms yourself is immoral, so sharing your achievements knowing they will be used against you would be acting immorally. Regarding your idea that the strike is a metaphor: I hadn't thought of that. Will consider it.

Comment: If acting in a way that harms yourself is immoral, then the [opportunity cost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_cost) of not sharing your achievements knowing they won't be used to benefit you would be acting immorally also. This is related to the strand in philosophical thinking that inaction is a form of action. Therefore, you cannot strip the act from the context as you attempt to do. Ethics in this way are often [situational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Situational_ethics).

Comment: It's our first impulse to reduce ethical precepts to categorical imperatives, but those imperatives, in the real world, must be applied [heuristically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic), not absolutely, because reason is [defeasible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defeasible_reasoning). Therefore the application of "Do not harm yourself" must be applied broadly across all aspects of one's life and seen in the widest possible terms given a variety of contexts. Hope that helps.

Comment: J D, re your first comment: this is an interesting problem readers of AS face when it comes to the question of what lessons from AS to apply to one's own life and how: specifically, whether one should 'quit'. I guess it involves weighing the cost of quitting against the cost of not quitting, each cost being a result of one's hierarchy of values.

Comment: Re your second comment, it sounds like you're saying *all* reason is defeasible. That doesn't sound right to me. All reason is *fallible*, sure – but, contra defeasibility, people do arrive at valid deductions sometimes. But yes your thoughts do help, thanks.

Comment: Upon further reading of Rand, I think JD's most recent comment is much lower quality than I thought. It contains a stolen concept (in the way it argues against absolutes), and, worse, it undercuts reason. I now don't think his comments were helpful after all.

Comment: Well, you're certainly entitled to thinking you are a judge of quality, though the Randbot tone of your last response switching from gratitude to accusations of dishonest seem to suggest that you might be emotionally quite invested in some absolute argument. The broader philosophical community of scholars tends to see Rand as a novelist turned dilettante epistemologist who seems to attract ideologues with an extreme libertarianism that makes it the far right counterpart of communism. Plato, Socrates, Descartes, Kant, Husserl, and Heidegger will be remembered... Rand is at best a foot note...

Comment: I didn't accuse you of dishonesty.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to view Rand in the social context of Communism.  Rand’s novels are mainly political, rather than philosophical, and she wrote to identify and oppose political enemies - one charitable interpretation might be to say that she mainly writes preventatively, rather than proscriptively, in order to try to prevent the collapse she sees as following from the worlds and forces she depicts in her novels.

Indeed, the world emerging in recent years seems very much a kind of plutocratic feudalism, where a select few wield disproportionate power as a consequence of market capitalism, that she would have highly approved of!  Why should Jeff Bezos strike when he does in fact have more money than he might ever reasonably expect to spend?

Comment: It sounds like you're shitting on Rand in a way I requested not to by describing a *philosopher's* magnum opus as "mainly political, rather than philosophical". Separately, I don't think she would have approved of what you consider "plutocratic feudalism", nor would she (presumably) have considered the current American economic system to be "market capitalism" but rather some sort of crony capitalism. But I think that's out of scope for my question unless you find some way to tie it back.

Comment: I dispute that!  The purpose of her work was very much to make a statement about the role of the individual in public life at a time in history where this was exactly the topic du jour, and Rand wrote as part of a general political campaign. It would not have furthered that campaign to disengage from it - hence, there is no inconsistency here, *because* the work is political. That’s not an attempt to denigrate, just an observation of the works’ context.

Comment: "Rand wrote as part of a general political campaign" What campaign?

Comment: Well American anti-communism, of course! Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayn_Rand#The_Fountainhead_and_political_activism , especially https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Alliance_for_the_Preservation_of_American_Ideals ,

Comment: I've read the links. I think you'll need more evidence to show that Rand's work is more political than it is philosophical. It sounds like you're underestimating her philosophical contributions, and maybe ignoring the fact that one's politics are downstream of one's political philosophy anyway.

Comment: @DennisHackethal -- philosophers in general have a very poor opinion of Rand as a philosopher.  She is seen as more of an apologist or promoter than a thinker.  This immediately raises the question of "apologist or promoter for WHAT"?  Which is what Paul Ross is answering -- a particular political agenda.

Comment: That most philosophers dislike Rand probably has to do with her criticizing academia instead of shmoozing, and not compromising and not being left-wing (whereas many philosophers are).

Comment: The reason so many philosophers get irritated with Objectivists is that Objectivists accuse them of denying the laws of identity, noncontradiction, excluded middle, etc. etc. etc. and yet hardly any philosophers do so. She also drastically misread Kant, to the point that she at least subconsciously plagiarized him twice over while accusing him of even worse things than she accused others of. All that being said, I think she had unusual and interesting opinions about specific technical questions and was very creative (e.g. as with the multiple-ending jury play she scripted, IIRC).

Comment: Philosophers may get irritated with Oists but it doesn't follow that Rand wasn't really a philosopher (you're not saying that directly; I'm clarifying). Nor does it follow from her alleged misreading and/or plagiarism of Kant (on the contrary, reading, interpreting, and writing about Kant are all philosophical tasks).

Comment: I perhaps don’t want to overstay this point about whether ideology or politics takes precedence, because it gets messy when you start asking about the relationship in an author between their experienced political history (eg. Rand ‘s experiences of Soviet Russia) and the positions they subsequently maintain in their works (anti-collectivist, anti-socialist and dystopian fiction and autobiography), but I think the evidence that Ellsworth Toohey is actually a critique of Harold Laski (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harold_Laski) is quite interesting given his explicitly political advocacy.

Comment: But I’m prepared to acknowledge I’m not overly interested in Rand’s work *after* Atlas Shrugged, which I understand to be mainly elaboration on the ideas presented in the novels rather than distinct work?  By this point, the geopolitics of Cold War start shifting and Detente no longer really meshes with her explicit hostility to communism, so it seems entirely explainable that she would settle into a more niche, abstract body of non-fiction writing.

Answer (score 0):

Individuals can't strike. They can only quit. Striking is a collective action. To do collective action, individuals must organize into a collective. The collective must control enough of the supply of the desired good that the cost of replacing them exceeds the long-term cost of acceding to their demands. To organize into a collective, individuals must communicate the desirability of organizing into a collective with other individuals.

I haven't read Rand, so it's possible that the question doesn't have the obvious answer... but the question appears to reduce to:

"If Rand desired to do something which she could not do except by organizing into a collective with other individuals, why did she attempt that which is required in order to organize into a collective with other individuals?"

Comment: Interestingly, I think Rand would probably have argued actively against the kind of Strike action you describe here. This, she would say, is a kind of ransom, where the individual withholding of labour rather than consenting to exploitation is a morally justified act of heroism.

Comment: g s, since you haven't read Rand: I think her focus on the individual implies that she would have advocated striking (or 'quitting') for individuals as well. In *Atlas Shrugged*, business magnates quit *one by one*, and not by appealing to their collectivist sensibilities like a union leader might. Regardless, Rand did succeed in forming a collective around her ideas, yet AFAIK, neither did that collective ever strike nor did any of its members ever quit.

Comment: @PaulRoss I'm guessing you mean 'whereas' instead of "where" or else it sounds like you're saying Rand would "argue[] actively against [a] kind of Strike action" she considers "a morally justified act of heroism".

Comment: i tend to agree with @PaulRoss but i'm just going on vibes. incidentallty, you can go on strike as one person, but it's slow work.